# Delete row from database in administrator

Tags: database, joomla, delete-row, corresponding-records

I have a component and I want to add a delete button in administrator, but I can't make it to work. Here is my code (all of the lines that are commented, I tried them):

```
`<?php `
`$db = JFactory::getDBO();`



`$query = $db->getQuery(true);`

/* ----------------- STERGERE -----------------------*/

    `if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    { $query->delete('*');

      $query->from('roy_testimonial');

      $query->where('testimonial_id = "'.$_GET['delete'].'"'); 

      $db->setQuery($query);

    }`
/* ----------------- END STERGERE -----------------------*/
/*-------------- AFISARE ------------------ */

`$query->select('*');`

`$query->from('roy_testimonial');`


`$db->setQuery($query);`

`$options = $db->loadAssocList();`

`foreach($options as $row) {

    $firstname = htmlentities($row['firstname']);

    $lastname  = htmlentities($row['lastname']);

    $city  = htmlentities($row['city']);

    $state  = htmlentities($row['state']);

    $mesaj  = htmlentities($row['user_mesaj']);

    $purchase  = htmlentities($row['your_purchase']);

    $sales  = htmlentities($row['sales']);

    $financing  = htmlentities($row['financing']);

    $service  = htmlentities($row['service']);

    $parts  = htmlentities($row['parts']);

    $accesories  = htmlentities($row['accesories']);

    $id = $row['testimonial_id'];`

/* ----------------- END AFISARE -----------------------*/


`?>`

`<div style="float:left;width:600px;">`

`<h2 style="color:#015CB7;"><?php echo $id; ?>) <?php echo $firstname;?> <?php echo $lastname;?>`

`<font style="color:#000;font-size:14px;">( <?php echo $city;echo ','; echo $state;?> )</font></h2>`

`<p>`

`<font style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">Mesaj:</font>  <?php echo $mesaj; ?></p>`

`</div>`

`<div style="float:left;width:300px;">`

<!-- RATING -->

`<h2 style="color:#015CB7">Rating</h2>`

`Your Purchase: <?php echo $purchase; ?> <br/>`

`Sales: <?php echo $sales; ?> <br/>`

`Financing and Insurance: <?php echo $financing; ?> <br/>`

`Service: <?php echo $service; ?> <br/>`

`Parts: <?php echo $parts; ?> <br/>`

`Accesories: <?php echo $accesories; ?> <br/>`

`</div>`

`<div style="float:right;width:300px;">`

`<a href="?delete=<?=$id;?>">Sterge</a>`
`</div>`

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`



`<?php } ?>`
```

This is what I have so far, should I use post instead of get?

Comment: And what is the `exact` error ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't have any error, it is just not deleting my row.

Comment: Hi, ok firstly, remove all the code you're not using, which will make it much easier to read. Secondly, don't use `$_GET`, have a read up on [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput). You have commented out both database query methods for your `delete` execution, which one are you using?

Comment: Ok, I will read that page. Thank you.

Comment: Also refrain from using `header(Location: ...)` when you can use Joomla's built in redirect methods ;) Once you've sorted all your code out, it will be much easier to provide a solid answer :)

Comment: this is what I'm using:  if(isset($_GET['delete']))
 { $query->delete('*');

      $query->from('roy_testimonial');

      $query->where('testimonial_id = "'.$_GET['delete'].'"'); 

      $db->setQuery($query);
   
   header("Location: /index.php?option=com_testimoniale");   
   


 }

Comment: as @Lodder said, just write what you have tried. Then print your query and try it directly in your database (phpMyAdmin or anything else). Maybe your Joomla/Php code is ok, it is just your SQL that is wrong ??

Comment: @RMissy - Please edit your question with the code you're using and remove any code that you're **not** using

Comment: Delete is not some unique thing. Lots of toolbars have it.  Don't reinvent the wheel, use the API.

Comment: @Elin, this is the solution that I found, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You actually set the query but did not execute it.
Add the following

`$db->query();`

after

```
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's the same.

Comment: $db->setQuery() and $db->query() are different, anyway to tell what query will be executed echo $query->dump(); Then we can see if the query was set well

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I used your idea too and it's the same. It doesn't work.